# how to output the child shell when tty is disabled

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

- I'm running my shell through an automation tool where tty is disabled.

## parent.sh

```
echo "parent shell"
./child.sh
```

## child.sh

```
echo child shell
```

- when i execute parent.sh on terminal console it will output me

  ```
  parent shell
  child shell
  ```
- But when i execute through my automation tool where tty is disabled. it output me only:

  ```
  parent shell
  ```
- Can someone explain why this behavior and how can i achieve other than redrect child shell output to another file and printing them.

Comment: Try an absolute path like `/path/to/child.sh` rather than `./child.sh`

Comment: @hek2mgl- child.sh is getting executed. even its output is directed to console. when tty is disabled, it doesn't child.sh output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. we have to call child shell using bash. 
i.e., bash child.sh

Reason behind this is, when we are calling child shell its getting executed in new shell and my automation tool prints the output in parent shell only. when i call using bash, it executes the child shell in parent shell.

Since i used bash shell, i'm executing with bash. for other shells you need to call child script with corresponding shell keyword.